# Wordpress images as subposts

Tags: wordpress, image

Is it possible to have images in a certain post to be showed as subposts? What I mean is a structure like this:

post - http://www.blog.com/some-post

I want all images in that post(10) to be shown like this when clicked
www.blog.com/some-post/image-1
www.blog.com/some-post/image-2
...
www.blog.com/some-post/image-10

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There are two Ways:

You can Create a page with Name: "some-post" and subpages for Images: "image-1", "image-2" and so on, and link them to your images.

Better and easier way, read this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Image_and_File_Attachments#Permalinks

Here the Example of the easier way:

If you Upload an image **image3.png** and insert it in your Post **sample-post**, than you can see the image under **http://domain.tld/link-to-your-sample-post/image3** just without the ending **.png or .jpg or .gif** or anything else, this is the easiest way..